# Vb.Net Incorrect syntax with SQL Query 

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

```
 Command = New OleDbCommand("SELECT dbo.tbl_staff.staff_id, dbo.tbl_staff.username, dbo.tbl_staff.password, dbo.tbl_useraccount.position_id " & _
                                "FROM dbo.tbl_position INNER JOIN " & _
                                "dbo.tbl_useraccount ON dbo.tbl_position.position_id = dbo.tbl_useraccount.position_id INNER JOIN " & _
                                "dbo.tbl_staff ON dbo.tbl_useraccount.useraccount_id = dbo.tbl_staff.staff_id " & _
                                "WHERE (dbo.tbl_staff.username = '" & TextBox1.Text & "') AND (dbo.tbl_staff.password = '" & TextBox2.Text & "')", Connection)
```

It says incorrect syntax.

Comment: Your way of coding is open to sql injections

Comment: "It says incorrect syntax" - strangely, the compiler is rarely wrong....Suggest you show us more of the actual code, and the line causing the error.

Comment: Please show exact error code, and surrounding lines of code to the included snipped

Comment: Are you sure that your textboxes don't contain any ' characters? Like the name O'brien for example? Using SQL Parameters rather than direct use of the UI field in SQL can help against this problem.

Comment: I was tempted to add this to my answer, but I'd rather force him to use SQL Parameters which would take care of it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How to run a SQL Server Query in VB.NET

1. **Create SQL Command** - You aren't setting the connection property of the SQLCommand. You can do this without adding a line of code. *This is the cause of your error.*

   ```
   myCommand = New SqlCommand("Insert Into MyTable values (@value1, @value2)", MyConnection)
   ```

   - Note: @value1, @value2 -- these come into play later. These are placeholders for SQL Parameters. These will save your butt.
2. **Insert Parameter Values** - You need to utilize SQL Parameters, despite the fact that you are not using a Stored Procedure. *This is not the cause of your error*.

   ```
   CMD.Parameters.Add("@value1", SqlDbType.Int).Value = CInt(TXT_BookdID.Text)
   CMD.Parameters.Add("@value2", SqlDbType.varchar, 500).Value = TXT_BookName.Text
   ```
3. **Create a function to execute your SQL Commands**

   ```
   ''' <summary>Executes a SqlCommand on the Main DB Connection. Usage: Dim ds As DataSet = ExecuteCMD(CMD) </summary>'
   ''' <param name="CMD">The command type will be determined based upon whether or not the commandText has a space in it. If it has a space, it is a Text command ("select ... from .."), '
   ''' otherwise if there's just one token, it's a stored procedure command</param>'
   Function ExecuteCMD(ByRef CMD As SqlCommand) As DataSet
       Dim connectionString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("main").ConnectionString
       Dim ds As New DataSet()

       Try
           Dim connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
           CMD.Connection = connection

           'Assume that it's a stored procedure command type if there is no space in the command text. Example: "sp_Select_Customer" vs. "select * from Customers"
           If CMD.CommandText.Contains(" ") Then
               CMD.CommandType = CommandType.Text
           Else
               CMD.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
           End If

           Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(CMD)
           adapter.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 300

           'fill the dataset'
           adapter.Fill(ds)
           connection.Close()

       Catch ex As Exception
           ' The connection failed. Display an error message.'
           Throw New Exception("Database Error: " & ex.Message)
       End Try

       Return ds
   End Function
   ```